# Python: transform scientific number to milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code looks like this:

```
   from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient()
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client.local
    orderbook = db.orderbook_update.find({'lastUpdated': 1538584913932}).limit(1)
    for order in orderbook:
            timestamp = order['lastUpdated']
            timestamp = timestamp - (timestamp%60000)
            timestamp_target = timestamp + 60000
    orderbook_target = db.orderbook_update.find({'lastUpdated': {'$lt':timestamp_target}}).limit(1)
    def to_millis(time):
      return int(pd.to_datetime(time).value / 1000000)

    print(timestamp_target)
    for orderb in orderbook_target:
        topAsk = orderb['asks'][0][0]
        topBid = orderb['bids'][0][0]

        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=monty user=postgres host=localhost password=postgres")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM binance.zrxeth_aggregated;")
        row = cur.fetchall()
        for r in row:
            ts = to_millis(r[0])
            ts_target = ts- (ts%60000)

            if ts_target == timestamp_target:
                query = 'INSERT INTO binance.zrxeth_aggregated(topBid,topAsk) VALUES (topBid,topAsk)'
                print(query)
                cur. execute(query)
                conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

However the last if is never true because ts_target is in milliseconds: 1538589840000 and timestamp_target is in scientific form: `1.53858492e+12`
does anyone have an idea on how to transform this number to milliseconds? Thanks!

Comment: I think regular expressions together with casting should resolve the issue.

Comment: what is the type of `timestamp_target`, is it string?

Comment: If your question is about converting between milliseconds and scientic format, do you think the rest of your code is relevant here? Should we have to sift through the parts where you call a bunch of queries on MongoDB? You should aim to make it as easy as possible for the Stackoverflow community to answer your *specific* question. See here for more guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Karl, come one Karl, don't be silly, I gave the entire code just to give an overview of the entire process that s it. It s not a long code either way

Comment: I'm not being silly. That is how Stackoverflow works. I gave you *advice* to help you get better answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it into a `float` or an `int`. That might work.

```
In [153]: a = 1.53858492e+12

In [154]: float(a)
Out[154]: 1538584920000.0

In [155]: int(a)
Out[155]: 1538584920000
```